# How to fix "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" using pymysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I'm having trouble connecting over SSH with pymysql to a remote MySQL database that's on an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server. However, connecting to the same server and database using MySQL Workbench over SSH gives no issues - no matter the query.

I've tried raising the `wait_timeout` and `interactive_timeout` to the MySQL server (to 8 hours), but nothing. The following code only works *once* in a while:

```py
# test.py

import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
SSHTunnelForwarder.SSH_TIMEOUT = 200.0
SSHTunnelForwarder.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 200.0

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('myhostname.net', 22),
    ssh_username='some_user',
    ssh_password='some_password',
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)
) as tunnel:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', 
        port=tunnel.local_bind_port, 
        user='admin', 
        password='password', 
        db='db'
    )
```

This is the output from running the above code fails (which is around 95% of the time):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    db='db'
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/the_bbc/application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/the_bbc/application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 325, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/the_bbc/application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 598, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/the_bbc/application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 975, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/the_bbc/application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 657, in _read_packet
    packet_header = self._read_bytes(4)
  File "/home/alex/Desktop/the_bbc/application/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 707, in _read_bytes
    CR.CR_SERVER_LOST, "Lost connection to MySQL server during query")
```

Is there anything I should investigate/try get the above code to work? Any advice is much appreciated!

Comment: What is your current connect_timeout value for MySQL?